# Wide tile for wp 7.1 app runned on wp8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I need to add wide tile template for my WP 7.1 app.
When it runned on wp8 devices, tile what I created from app list can not be expanded to "wide tile" how on image below.
[image: Tiles template example]

I only can set it to first and second position.

Can I add an image for wide template into wp 7.1 application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to do that.

- [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [Mangopolo](http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/) lib

[Here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/01/22/windows-phone-7-8-and-windows-phone-8-live-tile-light-up-for-windows-phone-os-7-1-apps.aspx?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) you can find an overview.